# Getting uid after createUser()

Tags: firebase

With iOS/MacOS is there a way to retrieve the uid immediately after `createUser`?

Our app allows an Admin user to create other user accounts (email/password authentication) and also stores some other info about the created user in our Firebase with the uid as the key.

One solution is when the admin creates the user (`createUser`), it's followed by authenticating the user, grabbing the uid from `FAuthData` that's returned and then create the key/value pair in our Firebase with the user data. Then that account is unauth'd.

In doing a Google search, there were a couple of references to something like this

```
-(void)createUser:(NSString *)email password:(NSString *)password withCompletionBlock(NSError *error, User *user) {block}
```

where it appears a user (or `FAuthData`?) was returned.

If no, what is the best practice to get the just-created uid? Is this a feature that is upcoming?

2/22/2016 update

For completeness, soon after I asked this question, Firebase was updated with a method that created the user and returns the uid at the time of creation:

> createUser:password:withValueCompletionBlock:

```
    - (void)createUser:(NSString *)email password:(NSString *)password 
            withValueCompletionBlock:(void ( ^ ) ( NSError *error, NSDictionary *result ))
```

The result dictionary contains newly-created user attributes, including uid.

Comment: I don't see a way in the API. But can't you simply log the user in the completion block, straight after creating them? Then you can read the uid from the `authUser:password:withCompletionBlock:` `authData` parameter.

Comment: Frank has the right answer here. See [angularFire-seed](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed/blob/master/app/js/simpleLogin.js#L60) for an example of this approach.

Comment: I believe that our current implementation matches that approach. Create user, authenticate user (log in), get the uid, and then create the user data in our Firebase.

Comment: Wouldn't authenticating another user log you out though?

Comment: I believe the approach you've outlined is the recommended approach by Firebase. ie: log the user in, in the completion block, right after creating the user.